# Tabbed time picker to select time range, android

Tags: android, datetimepicker

I'd like to select a start-time and an end-time.

[image]

As you can see, there are tabs to choose both ends of a time interval.

Would it be customize a library like the following to make it tabbed?

https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers/

Answer (score 2):

Check this library for selecting time ranges - 
https://github.com/tittojose/TimeRangePicker

Comment: thanks for making this library 
how can we use it with getFragmentManager()? As most of our code uses getFragmentManager() and we are developing for api level 21 or more

Comment: Thanks for creating such library, I want to ask you if I want to remove okay and cancel button from the "from tab"?